# Restrict GoogleAutocomplete search api for a particular city in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, api, google-maps, google-places-api

I have already restrict GoogleAutocomplete search api for a particular country say Bangladesh. Now I want to restrict it for Dhaka City which is a city of Bangladesh. My Code is Provided below

```
  APICommunicator *api = [[APICommunicator alloc] init];
             _searchTermArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];


           NSDictionary *arr = [api getGoogleAPIArrByPOST:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=%@&region=BD&components=country:BD&types=geocode&key=%@",searchTerms,API_KEY]parameter:nil];

            NSString *areaName;
            for (areaName in arr) {
                _searchTermArray=[[arr valueForKey:@"predictions"]valueForKey:@"description"];



            }
```

Please let me know the way or code how to restrict it for the city

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete#place_types), you may restrict results from a Place Autocomplete request to be of a certain type by passing a `cities` type parameter.

> the `cities` type collection instructs the Places service to return results that match `locality` or `administrative_area_level_3`.

Example:

A request for cities containing "Vict" with results in Brazilian Portuguese:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=Vict&types=(cities)&language=pt_BR&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

Hope this helps!